# reading a specific sector from mifare classic

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I would like to read sector 8 from mifare classic provided I already have the keys.

From documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html#authenticateSectorWithKeyA%28int,%20byte%5B%5D%29) on `authenticateSectorWithKeyA (int sectorIndex, byte[] key)`

> A failed authentication attempt causes an implicit reconnection to the
>   tag, so authentication to other sectors will be lost.

It sounds like I have to authenticate with all sectors? Is it possible that I only authenticate with sector 8 and get the data only from that sector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NFC java.io.IOException: Transceive failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401154/android-nfc-java-io-ioexception-transceive-failed)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first authenticate using authenticateSectorWithKeyA() (if you have key A, otherwise use [authenticateSectorWithKeyB()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html#authenticateSectorWithKeyB%28int,%20byte%5B%5D%29) with key B). If this returns false, the authentication has failed (your key was incorrect).

When this succeeds you can use [readBlock()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html#readBlock%28int%29) to read the data (for convenience, you can use [sectorToBlock()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html#sectorToBlock%28int%29) to convert from sector index to block index)

Don't worry about failed authentications: it will not affect the operation of your card.

Answer (score 1):

you should make new connection to the reader, then select card tag SN, Login to sector other than sector 0, if program get return code 0/success, then you can read/write data by block (16 bytes/block). otherwise it deny R/W operation and you need to start over.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only have to authenticate the sector you are reading from. But if you try to authenticate another sector and fail, you will have to re-authenticate the sector you have already successfully connected to.

Comment: so, I authenticate with that sector first before I read it? can you tell me the process of reading a sector? how does my program knows it's already authenticated and allow to read a sector? API does it automatically?

Comment: I think NFC guys response is right on, he explains it very well.